# correct way to multithread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, completable-future

normal version of searching for a number in an array:

```
boolean search(int x, int[] arr) {
           for (int i : arr) {
               if (i == x) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
```

my way of multithreading it:

```
boolean searchAsync(int x, int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
           if (lo == hi) {
               return x == arr[lo];
           }
           int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
           CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf = CompletableFuture.<Boolean>supplyAsync(() -> searchAsync(x, arr, lo, mid));
           boolean b = searchAsync(x, arr, mid + 1, hi);
           return cf.thenApply(a -> a | b).join();
       }
boolean searchAsync(int x, int[] arr) {
           return searchAsync(x, arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
       }
```

but it doesn't return anything

Comment: What do you mean with “it doesn't return anything”? Do you have an actual caller with actual data?

Comment: Works for me. I just made the methods static and ran them in a main method.

Comment: Note that this implementation will not be very efficient, as it will schedule as many jobs as there are elements in the array. Moreover, multithreading this would only be relevant for large arrays due to the overhead it adds. In any case, parallel streams would be more appropriate and simpler to use here.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threading a purely CPU-bound task is often hard, as it is difficult to evaluate the overhead of thread synchronization and avoid computing too much.

For instance here, you wouldn’t want to check each entry in a separate task, as the overhead would be higher than the task itself. Moreover you will also want to stop the process as soon as possible, i.e. as quickly as possible after finding a match.

Fortunately, Java 8 also provides [the `Stream` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), which easily handles parallelism for CPU-bound tasks that involve a (large) collection of data, so your method implementation simply becomes:

```
boolean searchAsync(int x, int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).parallel().anyMatch(i -> i == x);
}
```

(note that without the `parallel()` it becomes purely equivalent to your first example with the `for` loop)